# Binding current layout elements in Android MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

Is it possible to use data binding to bind current layout elements? For example I would like to show some text when checkbox is clicked, so I would like to have something like this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/myCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="check me"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some text"
    android:visibility="@{myCheckBox.isChecked() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

I know how to do this from java code, I just wonder if there is a way to implement such behaviour by only modifying xml files?

Comment: Some guy wrote stupid answer, I've politely replied in comment that he is incorrect, so he deleted his answer and then downvoted my question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create one observable field in your ViewModel.

```
 public class ViewModel {
        public ObservableBoolean mCheckBox = new ObservableBoolean(false);
    }
```

And modify your layout xml file:

```
  <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={viewModel.mCheckBox}"
    android:text="check me" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some text"
    android:visibility="@{viewModel.mCheckBox ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this make sense although as you wrote it requires ViewModel and java code while I'm more interested in solution which would be xml only. After all my checkbox has it's ID, so potentially TextView could reference it. But those are only my guesses and perhaps it's not possible.